# What causes CTRL-C trap echo to fail when using `tee` and no `--ignore-interrupts`?

Tags: bash, shell

This is a very specific question, but I am interested to know what causes this behaviour

**Observed**

Run the following command and trigger "CTRl-C" signal after the fist wait echo.

```
bash -c "trap 'echo trapped' EXIT; until false &>/dev/null; do echo 'Waiting...'; sleep 3; done" | tee /tmp/test.txt
```

Notice the following error:

> ^Cbash: line 1: echo: write error: Broken pipe

Now run the following command and do the same:

```
bash -c "trap 'echo trapped' EXIT; until false &>/dev/null; do echo 'Waiting...'; sleep 3; done" | tee -i /tmp/test.txt
```

Notice how there is no error and the trap message is correctly shown.

**Question**

What would cause this behaviour and why does it seem that I need to use the `-i/--ignore-interrupts` option in order to correctly support trapping with `tee`?

**Specs**

- GNU bash, version 5.1.12(1)-release

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What causes CTRL-C trap echo to fail when using `tee`

It told you:

```
write error: Broken pipe
```

Because `tee` terminated, Bash can't write data to the pipe, which causes it to fail.

> no `--ignore-interrupts`?

Because tee is not closed, Bash can write data to the pipe, so it does not exit.

> What would cause this behaviour

Typing ctrl+c or sending SIGINT woudl cause tee to terminate, closing the pipe, and making Bash unable to send any more data to the pipe. As you do. (?)

> why does it seem that I need to use the -i/--ignore-interrupts option in order to correctly support trapping with tee?

The statement in the question is false. The trap is executed, it just does not print the requested text, because the pipe is closed. the trap actually prints `bash: line 1: echo: write error: Broken pipe` error message.

I believe you meant to write the error to another file descriptor:

```
bash -xc "trap 'echo trapped >&2' ...
```

Also use `set -x` to debug your scripts, as above.

`until null` is super odd - just `while true` or `while :`. There is no command named `null`,  you could do `until false` but that's like double negation.

Comment: This makes sense. The output to the closed stdout caused the problem. I changed the example to not use `null` any more :) Thanks for the explanation!